# CSS List Item Vertical Alignment

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, listitem

I came across what I think is a CSS issue today that I've never seen before:

[image]

These are two separate ordered lists. and on the second list, the number 1 is aligned to the bottom of the bullet point, rather than to the top, which is the only way I've ever seen it before (and which is what I want).

The code for these two lists is identical, except that the first has no anchor tag, while the second one does:

[image]

This is part of a post on a WordPress site and the main CSS file for this theme, when unminified, is thousands of lines long and is therefore somewhat overwhelming to me.

As I have never seen bullet points formatted like this, and wasn't even aware it could be done, can anybody point me to what CSS feature I should be looking for in the CSS file so I can top-align the number to the associated text?

Thanks!

==========

UPDATE:

I think this is the CSS block that is controlling this formatting:

```
body.single .single-inner-wrapper article#single-article .entry-content a {
    color: #41b5f9;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1
}
```

Thanks for a suggestion by G-Cyr, I added a vertical-alignment:top to this section, and it appears to have moved the number on the second list from being bottom aligned to top aligned. where I want it.

Thanks to everybody who helped!

Comment: try to re-recreate a code that reproduce this

Comment: Here is a fiddle, but the issue isn't occurring here - https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/Lap3wy6k/3/

Comment: Jennifer, thanks. That's why I think it's something in the main CSS file for the theme, but it's so large and I have no idea what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you looked at the pseudo element content in the web inspector? I'm curious what those inspections look like and how they might differ.

Comment: you probably resetted display and vertical-align on <a> somewhere  in your code . See what it needs  https://jsfiddle.net/rynue9zL/

Comment: @G-Cyr inline-block seems to be enough alone

Comment: Here is an article explaining styling `ol`s in detail => https://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/

Comment: G-Cyr, your jsfiddle code has helped me fix it, I think. I added a vertical-align:top to the CSS block that I think is controlling this (the inline-block was already there), and it's fixed the formatting for me.

Comment: Temani, thanks. The CSS code that I think is driving the formatting of this code already has an inline-block, so that didn't appear to be enough - at least, not with the theme I'm using.

Comment: Powell_v2, thanks. That's an interesting approach, but I'm not sure I need that just now.

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters):

> CSS counters let you adjust the appearance of content based on its
>   location in a document.

Here's a short example showing how this would be used.

- Set default `list-style` to `none`
- Always reset the counter in the parent element
- Increment the counter number in each `li`
- Ensure `li` is relatively positioned
- Store the actual number plus the "." in pseudo element `content`
- Only show numbers for `li`s which are non-empty
- Style to your liking

[image]

```css
.my-list {
  counter-reset: my-list-title;
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.my-list li {
  counter-increment: my-list-title;
  position: relative;
}

.my-list li:not(:empty)::before {
  content: counter(my-list-title) ".";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -1.2em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="my-list">
  <li>xxxx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx</li>
  <li>xxxx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx</li>  
</ol>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/54gtL2np/)

Comment: Andy, that's an interesting technique thanks. It's actually the styling, not the numbering, that is my problem here, but I think G-Cyr may have pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Mark Gotcha. I'll pay closer attention to the question next time around.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the CSS block that is controlling this formatting:

```
body.single .single-inner-wrapper article#single-article .entry-content a {
    color: #41b5f9;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1
}
```

Thanks for a suggestion by G-Cyr, I added a vertical-alignment:top to this section, and it appears to have moved the number on the second list from being bottom aligned to top aligned. where I want it.

Thanks to everybody who helped!

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this with a very simple trick

https://codepen.io/h-sharma/pen/VwaJmPy

```
     <ol>
      <li>
       <div>
        Some text.....
       </div>
      </li>
     </ol>
     <style>
      li>div{
       display:inline-block;
       vertical-align:bottom;
      }
     </style>
```

```css
li>div{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>
  <div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula,     
  </div>
 </li>
</ol>
```